# Page test in Experience Optimization on Azure Fails

Tags: azure, content-testing, experience-optimization

[image]Sitecore Experience Optimization Page Testing.

On Sitecore 9, I am trying to test created simple page in Experience Optimization. Locally everything working fine. When i tried same steps in Azure environment it giving me errors like below.

> HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the
>   server due to invalid syntax. (XHR)POST -
>   https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/api/sitecore/Settings/SetUserProfileKey
>
> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition
>   that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (XHR)GET -
>   https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/shell/api/ct/ItemInfo/GetByUri?datauri=sitecore%3A%2F%2F%7BED7C2C82-114C-4FB1-96A7-6CCF1F37317B%7D%3Fver%3D2%26lang%3Den&_=1518266879976
>
> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition
>   that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (XHR)GET -
>   https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/shell/api/ct/ItemInfo/GetByUri?datauri=sitecore%3A%2F%2F%7BED7C2C82-114C-4FB1-96A7-6CCF1F37317B%7D%3Fver%3D2%26lang%3Den&_=1518266879972

Please find attached screenshots for same.

Comment: This is a stretch... But I think you are hitting the URL max length, with the length of your domain name.  Can you shorten your machine names?

Comment: What you see is server response, actual error should be logged to App Insights